# Dynamo DB mapper not saving base class elements to DB when invoked on child class

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

The problem is that I am not able to save base class members to DB on invoking .save() on child class.

I have two classes class A, class B, I have three common members in both these class creationTimestamp, lastUpdatedTimestamp, version, as these were common I thought I will move them in a base class lets say Class C. But when I do mapper.save() on object of class A, I do not get the members of class C in DB.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamoDBDocument
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
abstract class C {
    @DynamoDBVersionAttribute
    private Long version;

    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy = DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedTimestamp
    private Long creationTimestamp;

    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy = DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS)
    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedTimestamp
    private Long lastUpdatedTimestamp;
}
```

Class A:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "A")
public class A {
    private String id;
}
```

Now if I do mapper.save() on object of class A it only saves id to db.

```java
A a = A.builder().id("random").build();
mapper.save(a);
```

Rather it should have showed version, creationTimestamp, lastUpdatedTimestamp, id any ideas what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your class `A` needs to extend class `C`

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "A")
public class A extends C {
    private String id;
}
```